# How to publish or replace the data to the feature layer hosted?

Tags: arcgis-pro, sql, sql-server, arcgis-python-api

A little background: My teammate has created a hosted feature layer. I access the data of hosted feature layer using ArcGIS API for Python and pull the data.

The hosted feature layer he created doesn't have a underlying dataset or geodatabase. I used this code snippet to confirm:

```py
feature_layer_url = ""
layer = arcgis.features.FeatureLayer(feature_layer_url, gis=gis)

# Check if the layer has an underlying dataset or geodatabase
if hasattr(layer, "properties") and "source" in layer.properties:
    source = layer.properties["source"]
    if source["type"] == "Feature Service":
        print("The layer is based on a feature class or shapefile.")
    elif source["type"] == "Table":
        print("The layer is based on a database table.")
    elif source["type"] == "Workspace":
        if source["dataset"].endswith(".gdb"):
            print("The layer is based on a geodatabase feature class.")
        elif source["dataset"].endswith(".sde"):
            print("The layer is based on a database feature class.")
else:
    print("The layer does not have an underlying dataset or geodatabase.")
```

Currently, in order to publish data into the Survey123 App, he navigates to the media folder, save the .csv file, and then publish the data to the form. We are currently seeking to streamline this process. I provide him the .csv file.

Is it possible to connect to the ArcGIS cloud  from a separate SQL server database and update the feature layer data(like linked server)? Alternatively, is there a method to use Python scripts to publish data from a large .csv file directly to the feature layer? or I am wondering is there a way to update field values of a hosted feature layer original tables.